# How to get first and second max using agg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
id   type1           val
a    main             3
a    main             5
a    main             4
b    second           80
b    second           90
```

I want to do groupby on columns id type1 and max() by val and also get the corresponding index of the max observation. I do this:

```
df.groupby(["id","type1"])["val"].agg("max", "idxmax")
```

I get:

```
id   type1        max   idxmax   

a    main          5    1
b   second        90    4
```

But i want to get first and second max:

```
id   type1        max   idxmax   

a    main          5    1
a    main          4    2
b   second        90    4
b    second       80    3
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `nlargest(n)` ([here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) the docs)

```
df.groupby(["id","type1"])["val"].agg("nlargest", 2)

id  type1    
a   main    1     5
            2     4
b   second  4    90
            3    80
```